# Is possible to create a script sql from Postgresql, but select only some columns?

Tags: postgresql

I have to insert a lot of lines (over 100) from a Postgresql db, to Oracle db.
I know a lot of solutions, writing on Oracle using oracle_fdw, create a csv file then using sqlloader, but I want a very fast solution, a sql script.
I know is possible create a sql script with this command

```
pg_dump --table=mytable --data-only --column-inserts mydb > data.sql
```

then import on Oracle db is easy.

I need something like this but with a difference, I want to export on data.sql, only some columns starting after a column id, i know is possible but is csv format

```
psql -c "copy(SELECT columns1,col2,col3... FROM mytable offset 3226 rows fetch first 100 rows only) to stdout" > dump.csv
```

is possible something like this but with sql format?

Comment: Why not use the CSV file together with Oracle's SQL\*Loader?

Comment: I know this solution, but a sql script is more simple and fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

A nice way is to create a view

```
CREATE view foo2 AS
SELECT col1,col2,col4 FROM mytable
offset 3226 rows fetch first 129 rows only;
```

you export the view and voilà...empty file!

This is because pg_dump man said

```
 It will not dump the contents of views or materialized views, and the
           contents of foreign tables will only be dumped if the corresponding foreign server is specified with
           --include-foreign-data.
```

So we create a temporary table

```
CREATE table foo2 AS
SELECT col1,col2,col4 FROM mytable
offset 3226 rows fetch first 129 rows only;
```

and export to sql script with pg_dump

```
pg_dump --table=mytable --data-only --column-inserts mydb > mydata.sql
```

after import to other db (first control values)

we can drop the temporary table

```
drop table foo2
```